# How to set the results of multiple api calls into an array - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component where i am display information about products. I have my first api call as:

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(state.source.api + "/cocart/v1/products?category=" + category.name)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setProducts(data);
      });
  }, []);
```

Which is displayed like this:

```
<>
  {products.map(
    ({ id, name, price, categories, _links }) => {
      return (
        <>
          <p>{name}</p>

          <div>
            {_links.variations.map((item) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <Variation itemname={name} href={item.href} />
                </>
              )
            })}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
  )}
</>
```

And the result of `console.log(products)` is:

[image]

i display each product's info in a div where the main thing i need to display correctly is the pricing. Due the the fact that each product has different sizes that are difference prices, i need to show a range (i.e. $100 - $200), to represent that each product can range from $100-$200. In order to do that, i need to fetch the api for each product variant. Each product variant's url is listed within the product data. So, for each product, I am then looping through each of it's variants, fetching the variants url, and returning the data for each variant.. which is what contains the variant's price. i do this using:

```
const Variation = ({ href, itemname }) => {
  const [varData, setVarData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(href)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setVarData(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {console.log(varData)}
      <p>{varData.price}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

The result of `console.log(varData)` is:

[image]

My issue is, I am needing each response of `varData` for a product to be returned in an array. this is a bit complicated, so if I need to provide more code let me know. Any help would be great.

Comment: Does the original endpoint that returns the list of products not contain price information about the variant?

Comment: no, it doesnt, it just provides each variants href

Comment: do you have control over the api where you can add it? because if you have 10 products returned in the list and then each product has 5 variants you are going to have to make 50 HTTP requests which probably isn't a good idea

Comment: hmm, it's through the woocommerce api. i can look into it, thanks for bringing that up, it's a good point

Comment: @kyle i dont think it's possible to edit the api for this situation